# No suitable driver exception while grail tomcat deployment

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, grails-orm, spring-orm

I have deployed a grails application into tomcat container but am getting No suitable driver exception: can any one help in solving this.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader Listener org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'h ibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExc eption: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:  Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class  'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:xxxx:oracle://xxxxx:1521;ServiceName=xxxx'> 

        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator.postProcessBeanFactory(PersistenceContextInterce ptorAggregator.groovy:104) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve refe rence to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframewo rk.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons .dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:xxxx:oracle://xxxx :1521;xxxx=xxxx'
        ... 1 more


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init meth od failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exc eption is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:in formatica:oracle://xxxx:1521;xxx=xxx'
        ... 1 more


Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache .commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:xxx:oracle://xxxx:1521;xxxx=xxxx'
        ... 1 more


Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc: xxxx:oracle://xxxx:1521;xxxx=xxxx'
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        ... 1 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
        ... 3 more

May 30, 2013 7:31:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 30, 2013 7:31:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/Jarvis] startup failed due to previous errors
May 30, 2013 7:31:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Was it working for you in embedded Tomcat? (`grails run-app`). Looks like you are missing the dependency on `ojdbc*.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED for a dependency definition example**

Add the following repository definition to your *BuildConfig.groovy*

```
mavenRepo "https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo"
```

In your dependencies section the following should appear:

```
runtime 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3'
```

A better way is to [install manually](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) the Oracle driver to your corporate Repository(Artifactory, Nexus, Archiva, file server, etc.)

Comment: I have added oracle ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar to build path and from  the embedded Tomcat? (grails run-app) application loads and runs. if i create a war then deploy it into separate tomcate then it throws the above exception.

Comment: If you follow the suggestion of my answer your problem will vanish. If adding a maven repository is complicated for you, add the driver to the lib folder of your Grails project.